# Jquery Multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have two buttons within my form. Each of them should submit the form to a different PHP file (one normal submit and one ajax call). At least that's the idea. When I click the buttons nothing happens. I've looked at other questions here on stackoverflow, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

#### HTML:

```
<form id="sform" name="sform" method="post" action="answer.php" class="sform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Option 1
<select id="option1" name="option1">
<option selected>None</option>
<option>Yellow</option>
<option>Green</option>
<option>Red</option>
</select>
<br>
Option 2
<select id="option2" name="option2">
<option selected>None</option>
<option value="F">Purple</option>
<option value="M">Brown</option>
<option value="T">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>

<textarea class="input-block-level" id="summernote" name="summernote" rows="18"></textarea>

<input type='button' value='Submit form' id="view" name="view"/>
<input type='button' value='Submit form' id="send" name="send"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$( "#send" ).click(function() {
    alert("hi");
   $("#sform").submit();
}



$( "#view" ).click(function() {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        /*url = $form.attr( 'action' ),*/
        postData = {
            option1: $form.find( '#option1' ).val(),
            option2: $form.find('#option2').val(),
            message: $form.find('#summernote').val(),
            js: 'true'
        };

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reply.php",
        data: postData,
        success: function(response){
            jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
        }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: If you are going to reference the event that was triggered, always pass it into the event handler as not all browser make it a global variable.

Comment: If the button is a submit button, why do you call submit on the form it is in?

Comment: Also in the case of the view click, 'this' is not the form.  'this' is the view button. $(this).closest('form') would be the form.

Comment: try `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

The call to `.click()` is not closed:

```
$( "#send" ).click(function() {
    alert("hi");
    $("#sform").submit();
}
//^ need closing parenthesis
```

So to make it complete by adding the closing parenthesis after the function brackets (i.e. `);`):

```
$( "#send" ).click(function() {
    alert("hi");
    $("#sform").submit();
});
```

As **Taplar** mentioned in a comment on your question, the *event* reference should be passed to the callback :

```
$("#view").click(function(event) {

 /* stop form from submitting normally */
 event.preventDefault();
```

Per the comment by **epascarello**, you can make the button that submits the form a regular submit button:

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit form' id="send" name="send" />
```

In doing that, the click handler on that input becomes superfluous.

And we can make the *send* button a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element instead of an input with `type="button"`

```
<button id="view" name="view">View</button>
```

Also note that calling [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on `$(this)` bound to the click handler associated with the element with **id** attribute *view* will find no elements under that button. In order to get the values of the elements under the form as it is structured, you should set `$form` to the parent element of the button (i.e. `$(this)`) - e.g.:

```
var $form = $(this).parent()
```

See the example below (Note: the form will not get submitted per the StackOverflow sandbox environment - to see the form submission in action, see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVr210Y9IFmRiyXui2qa?p=preview)).

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //when we change the input type to 'submit' for this button then this becomes un-needed
   /*$("#send").click(function() {
     alert("hi");
     $("#sform").submit();
   });*/
   $("#view").click(function(event) {

     /* stop form from submitting normally */
     event.preventDefault();

     /* get some values from elements on the page: */
     var $form = $(this).parent(),
         /*url = $form.attr( 'action' ),*/
         postData = {
           option1: $form.find( '#option1' ).val(),
           option2: $form.find('#option2').val(),
           message: $form.find('#summernote').val(),
           js: 'true'
         };
     /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
     jQuery('#result').append('would trigger AJAX call');
console.log('form data to submit',postData);
     //disabling this since we have no reply.php available
     /*jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "reply.php",
       data: postData,
       success: function(response) {
         jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
       }
     });*/
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sform" name="sform" method="post" action="answer.php" class="sform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Option 1
  <select id="option1" name="option1">
    <option selected>None</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
  </select>
  <br> Option 2
  <select id="option2" name="option2">
    <option selected>None</option>
    <option value="F">Purple</option>
    <option value="M">Brown</option>
    <option value="T">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <textarea class="input-block-level" id="summernote" name="summernote" rows="18"></textarea>

<button id="view" name="view">View</button>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit form' id="send" name="send" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery( "#send" ).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery( "#view" ).trigger( "click" );
    }

    jQuery( "#view" ).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm('#sform');
    });

    function submitForm(id) {

        var formId = id;
        var $form = $(formId),
            /*url = $form.attr( 'action' ),*/
            postData = {
                option1: $form.find( '#option1' ).val(),
                option2: $form.find('#option2').val(),
                message: $form.find('#summernote').val(),
                js: 'true'
            };

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reply.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(response){
                jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing closing bracket for the `#send` function.
Also, pass in the event to the functions, and "this" refers to the button, not the form, so use "closest" to find the form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#send").click(function(e) {
        alert("hi");
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sform").submit();
    });



    $("#view").click(function(e) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        e.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this).closest("form");
        var postData = {
                option1: $form.find('#option1').val(),
                option2: $form.find('#option2').val(),
                message: $form.find('#summernote').val(),
                js: 'true'
            };

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reply.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
            }
        });

    });
});
```